# Refreshig an IP camera image code with html code works only locally

Tags: html, image, ip-camera

I am trying to make a simple html page to periodically refresh an image captured from an IP camera.
The strange is that the code works perfectly when I execute it locally (loading my simple html page on chrome). But when I upload it to my web server (hostinger is the host), it fails to display the image.

The code is

```
<img src="http://sotiritsa.dyndns.org:81/cgi-bin/snapshot.cgi?cmd=snapPicture2&usr=XXXXXXX&pwd=XXXXXXXXX&t=" onload='setTimeout(function() {src = src.substring(0, (src.lastIndexOf("t=")+2))+(new Date()).getTime()}, 1000)' onerror='setTimeout(function() {src = src.substring(0, (src.lastIndexOf("t=")+2))+(new Date()).getTime()}, 5000)' alt='image of my city' title='Image of my city' />
```

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the error.
It has to do with the "https" and "http"
The ip camera is "http" and the web server page is "https"
If I call the simple page from web server with "http" and not "https", the code works